# Index-Match with different with different dimension

Tags: google-sheets

I got man-hour in sheet "Mon-Sun" and wanted to put it in the "Work hour" sheet.

I have been trying Index - Match.

I can get the row number by using "=match(if(isblank(E$2),D$2,E$2),'Mon-Fri'!$A$3:$A$9,0)"
but cannot seem to fine a way to match the ID to get column num.

Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15DlgOdeQ_Dbbmc9_Z62Oegpq_RjPwsL6mjugiK-ayB0/edit?usp=sharing

If there are other ways to do this please advise me.

Answer (score 0):

You want to insert a formula in a cell in "Word Hour" that return you the column number in "Mon-Fri" which contains the ID specified in column "A" of the row in which your cell   is contianed?

You can type e.g.

`=match($A4,'Mon-Fri'!$A$1:$CG$1,0)`

in `E4` - when you copy paste the formula to other cells - they will automatically take the correct row